# MS-Access 07 works the same way as MS-Access 03 on different machines or need installation?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, ado.net, database-connection

I m creating a window application using MS-Access as my database since data volume is not large.

I want to create it in accdb format i.e office 2007 then will it work with my application on any machine where there is no MS Office as mdb works on any machine.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're compiling for 64-bit Windows, you need to use the beta of the ACE that is part of the A2010 beta. Otherwise, you're limited to a 32-bit app because until A2010, there is no 64-bit version of Jet/ACE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install drivers: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en

Comment: @Remou: Could you plz be more descriptive abt installing driver. Why it is needed and do i need to install it if i m installing .net framework. Do both these parts are completly isolated ?

Comment: The Jet driver is installed with all recent versions of Windows, but it is not compatible with the accdb format, which is available as a download (link above). The new driver is backwards compatible, so it can be used with mdb as well as accdb formats. It is not installed with .Net framework, as far as I know.